# Can we use Poisson regression model to predict the effect of misinformation on user engagement on social media posts

Tags: poisson-regression, social-network

Our research question is what is the effect of misinformation on user engagement on social media posts. The unit of analysis is a social media post. Misinformation is an indicator variable and the independent variable. Engagement is integer counts and the dependent variable. It is the sum of number of views, reactions, and comments on a post. On our data, our engagement values are highly skewed, with many zeros.

Is Poisson regression (or zero-inflated poisson) a good model for this question?

Comment: It might be. More likely it will be a (zero-altered or inflated) negative binomial though. Poisson is quite a restrictive model and often doesn't fit messy real world situation.